# If a robots.txt file only lists a single user-agent, are other bots allowed to crawl?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

In the following robots.txt file, it says to disallow all directories for magpie-crawler. Let's say I was using a different web crawler like Scrapy. This robots.txt doesn't list anything else, so would a scrapy bot be allowed to scrape?

```
User-agent: magpie-crawler
Disallow: /


Sitemap: https://www.digitaltrends.com/sitemap_index.xml
Sitemap: https://www.digitaltrends.com/news.sitemap.google.xml
Sitemap: https://www.digitaltrends.com/image-sitemap-index.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official website](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html), this does mean that only that single bot is disallowed. You may, if desired, use Scrapy.

If they wanted, they could have only allowed one bot:

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow: 

User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the data using Scrapy. Just describe in the header that you are WEB-BROWSER in Scrapy settings:

```
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36'
```